# Content type node not overwriting the default node.tpl.php even if I have cleared all cache's

Tags: theming, nodes

I have a content type with a machine name of 'empresas' after reading the documentation I should be able to just create a node--empresas.tpl.php to toy with the output of this in my theme.

it seems to be not overwriting it. I am trying to hack something together and I am using the twitter bootstrap Drupal theme.

I have seem a similiar problem into another post in this forum but it seems like taht is not may problem because he have solve it by clearen all the cache's but that was not my case.

Comment: I am sure you have read the docs but:

https://www.drupal.org/node/17565

What you describe should work...you have cleared the cache...quite strange...are you directly modifying the Bootstrap theme or did you create a new theme and use bootstrap as a base?

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for your early help, and second yes I had readed the docs the thing is I was doing some research about this case and i have found that my problem was that I had activated Display Suite modulo, so the node--empresas.tpl.php was not showing... My mistake since I am new using drupal, I have disabled display duite module and I can see the modification of this node--empresas.tpl.php so in that case I was ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Drupal is incredibly robust and sophisticated...lots of points of failure which are hard to troubleshoot...but its an awesome system when it all works :)

Comment: While not an answer, have you taken a look at the devel_themer module? It can really help figuring out what template or function is rendering certain areas? https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look to the devel_themer module, i have seen the very difference between drupal and other CMS and is for much a incredible all the things taht you can do with it, it is my first time since I have been working developing some graphics for a huge multisite that was developed in drupal 7 and I was amazed for all the things that you can do, so I will dig deeper in the documentation but it is so much that I dont know for sure qhere to start, thaks for your advice I'm sure It will be very helpfull.

Comment: are you also using Display Suite ?

Answer (score 0):

Initially, i say like not to override the original theme folder,

Create a sub theme of the base theme, in your case create a sub-theme of twitter bootstrap.
Then make the necessary changes in the sub-theme.

Enable only the sub theme.

And about overriding `node.tpl.php` file,
your approach is correct `node--empresas.tpl.php`, should over-ride the display of this particular node content.

Cross check machine name, Enabled theme, path of the overriding tpl.php file.